# Button in View Should Reset Array in ModelController But Doesn't

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am attempting have one of my views present the user with the option to reset an array that they have edited to it's original form. I am currently attempting to do this using NSNotificationCenter.

The current process:

1. User flips through a series of cards, each of which are pulled from the array experiments (which has been shuffled beforehand but I don't think that's relevant to this issue) and deletes ones they don't want to see again when the array loops back around.
2. User decides they want to start again with a fresh array.
3. User clicks "Home" which brings them to AdditionalMenuViewController.swift which is set up with NSNotification center with an @IBAction that triggers the notification that the ModelController will listen to. Here's AdditionalMenuViewController.swift.

   ```
   let mySpecialNotificationKey = "com.example.specialNotificationKey"

   class AdditionalMenuViewController: UIViewController {


   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "resetArray", name: mySpecialNotificationKey, object: nil)
   }


   @IBAction func notify(){
       NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(mySpecialNotificationKey, object: self)
   }

   func resetArray() {
       println("done")
   }
   }
   ```
4. That should trigger the listener in ModelController to reset the array and then allows the user to continue using the app but with the array reset. Here are the (I think!) relevant parts of ModelController.swift:

   ```
   class ModelController: NSObject, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

   var experiments = NSMutableArray()
   var menuIndex = 0

   func shuffleArray(inout array: NSMutableArray) -> NSMutableArray
   {
   for var index = array.count - 1; index > 0; index--
   {
       // Random int from 0 to index-1
       var j = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(index-1)))

       // Swap two array elements
       // Notice '&' required as swap uses 'inout' parameters
       swap(&array[index], &array[j])
   }
       return array
   }

   override init() {
   super.init()
   // Create the data model.

           if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("experiments", ofType: "plist") {
       if let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) {
           experiments.addObjectsFromArray(dict.objectForKey("experiments") as NSArray)
       }
   }

   println(experiments)

   shuffleArray(&experiments)

   println(experiments)

   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "resetArray", name: mySpecialNotificationKey, object: nil)
   }

   func resetArray() {
   if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("experiments", ofType: "plist") {
       if let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) {
           experiments.addObjectsFromArray(dict.objectForKey("experiments") as NSArray)
       }
   }

   shuffleArray(&experiments)
   }
   ```

Currently it does create a new array but it is double the size of the original which tells me its running both the original and the reset functions. It also breaks all the pageViewController functionality that you can find in the default Page-Based Application in Xcode.

What am I missing here?

How can I both reset the array and then drop the user back into the flow of the Page-Based App?

Comment: You never clear out your array before adding objects to it in resetArray(). Add a line, experiments.removeAllObjects() before you call addObjectsFromArray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rdelmar's suggestion worked perfectly. I now clear the array and then fill it with a freshly shuffled one.